# APIって作れますか？

Tags: api, chatgpt

タイトルにもあるとおりAPIってつくれますか？ChatGPTのAPIは現在有料ですがAPIを作ることによって無料で使えるように出ませんか？もしAPIが作れるのならAPIをどうやって作るのか大雑把でいいので教えて欲しいです。参考になるようなURLやサイトもあれば送って欲しいです。私はChatGPTのAPIを作りたいです。

Comment: API と呼ばれるものを作ることは恐らく可能でしょうが、だからといって 「ChatGPT が無料で使える」には話が繋がりません。

Comment: APIが何かを分かっていない気がしますが・・・。有料のものを無料で使いたい、というのは原則無理だと思います。ChatGPTに拘らず似たようなサービスを探すとか自力でAIを作成する方向で考えた方が良いのではないでしょうか？AIを作成すると言っても1から作成するのではなくファインチューニングである程度良いものは作成可能かと思います。

Comment: ウェブ画面のUIは無料で使えるわけで、それをプログラムからアクセスしたいという意味でしょう。そしたら正規のAPIにお金を払わなくて済む...。PythonならFastAPIとSeleniumとタスクキューを使えば簡単にできそうです。

Answer (score 3):

`API` って Application Programming Interface ってことで、要するに

- ある機能を提供する側がいて (例えば ChatGPT を提供する側)
- その機能を使いたい側がいて (例えばあなたやオイラ)
- 提供側が事前に定めた「その機能を使うための手続き」のことです。

例１： OS とアプリケーションプログラムがあるとき「ファイルの開き方」
例２：検索エンジンと使用者がいるとき「検索の仕方」
例３： ChatGPT とユーザーがいるとき「質問の仕方」

そして API の使用料金は　API を**提供する側**が決めるものです。「１回でも使うためには事前登録が必要で有料です」と決めて API を提供しているなら有料だし、「１日１００回までなら無料です」なら上限を超えない限り無料です。 API という文言は、それだけでは有料とか無料とか一切関係ありません。

あなたが Chatbot を作って他人に提供するのなら API （っつかライセンス）を有料にするも無料にするもあなたの判断です。あなたの作った Chatbot が、実は中でこっそり ChatGPT を使っているのであれば

- あなたは ChatGPT の API を使う側
- あなたはあなたの作った Chatbot 用の API を提供する側
- あなたの提供する API を無料にするのも有料にするのもあなたの判断

  - あなたの提供する API が無料で、あなたの使う ChatGPT API が有料なら、その料金はあなたの持ち出しになる
  - 持ち出しが嫌ならあなたの提供する API も有料になるだろう

ってだけの話。

# API **もどき**ってのもおかしな話。あなたが、あなたの作った Chatbot を一定の手続きで皆に使わせるのならそれは **立派な API** であってもどきではない。
# あなた**が** ChatGPT の API を提供することはありえない（あなたが ChatGPT の作者であるなら話は別）

Comment: 成る程。そういう作りになってるんですね。私が言ってるAPIもどきっていうのが完全にはアプリケーション同士連携せずChatGPTの回答のテキストだけコピペして返すっていう作りを考えてたんですが話を聞いてる感じ無理っぽいですね。

Answer (score 2):

(ChatGPTを含む)いくつかの学習済モデルを利用するためのAPIが、
OpenAI社より、提供されています。
言語はPythonです。他言語は分かりません。
最初は無料でいくらかAPIを呼び出すことができます。
その後リミットに達すると、課金するまで利用できなくなります。

「参考になるようなURLやサイト」です。
https://platform.openai.com/docs/introduction
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference
Chromeの自動翻訳機能で、思ったより読めるかと思います。

以下は、APIの大雑把な利用例です。

```bash
# APIを呼び出すためのモジュールのインストール方法です。
!pip3 install openai
```

APIを利用する例

```py
import typing as t
import openai

# <https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys>にログインし、API Keyを作成します。
# 作成したAPI Keyを、以下の変数[openai.api_key]に設定する必要があります。
openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

request = {
    'max_tokens': 1024,
    'n': 1,  # 回答の数
    'temperature': 0.5,  # 0で毎回同じ結果を戻す
    'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',  # モデルは、ChatGPT3.5 Turbo
    'messages': [
        {'role': 'system', 'content': 'あなたは役に立つアシスタントです。'},
        {'role': 'user', 'content': '日本の首都はどこですか？'},  # ←質問内容
    ],
}
# APIを呼び出し
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(**request).to_dict_recursive()
# 実行結果を表示
print(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
```

実行結果

```
日本の首都は東京です。
```

Comment: 私はChatGPTのAPIもどきみたいなのを作りChatbot的なものを作りたいのですがその場合でも有料になりますか？

Comment: API自体は裏でアプリケーション同士の連携を指すことはわかってますが、APIもどきみたいなものでも繋げたいアプリケーションが有料な場合は必ず有料になるんですか？私は作ったことないからわかりませんが